# Is there a way to change CSS of Unity WebGL builds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unity-game-engine

I am building a WebGL Unity 3D game and want to make some css changes to the webGL build but I am failing to do so. For example I want to be able to move my game to the center of the page and give it a border. Is that possible? Is there a way to do it using browser scripting?

I have been able to create a plugin that embeds an iframe in the build but other than that I wasn't able to change the css

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. When you build your game for WebGL, you already use a [template HTML page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html) where the webGL content is integrated in. You have full control over those templates. Though even when you just use one of the default testing templates, you can edit them after the build. A Unity build doesn't really haev any html elements besides the canvas element. So what elements you want to format with your changed CSS?